# Connect timed out error in youtube data search api

Tags: java, eclipse, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to list data on the basis of keywords given to youtube data api as parameter .

```
public class Search {

/**
 * Define a global variable that identifies the name of a file that
 * contains the developer's API key.
 */
private static final String PROPERTIES_FILENAME = "youtube.properties";

private static final long NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED = 25;

/**
 * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
 * to make YouTube Data API requests.
 */
private static YouTube youtube;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Read the developer key from the properties file.
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        InputStream in = Search.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
        properties.load(in);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("There was an error reading " + PROPERTIES_FILENAME + ": " + e.getCause()
                + " : " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests. The last
        // argument is required, but since we don't need anything
        // initialized when the HttpRequest is initialized, we override
        // the interface and provide a no-op function.
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            }
        }).setApplicationName("Testing").build();

        // Prompt the user to enter a query term.
        String queryTerm = getInputQuery();

        // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
        YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

        // Set your developer key from the {{ Google Cloud Console }} for
        // non-authenticated requests. See:
        // {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}
        //String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
        //search.setKey(apiKey);
        search.setQ(queryTerm);
        search.setType("video");
        search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
        search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);


        SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
        List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
        if (searchResultList != null) {
            prettyPrint(searchResultList.iterator(), queryTerm);
        }
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                + e.getDetails().getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * Prompt the user to enter a query term and return the user-specified term.
 */
private static String getInputQuery() throws IOException {

    String inputQuery = "";

    System.out.print("Please enter a search term: ");
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    inputQuery = bReader.readLine();

    if (inputQuery.length() < 1) {
        // Use the string "YouTube Developers Live" as a default.
        inputQuery = "YouTube Developers Live";
    }
    return inputQuery;
}

/*
 * Prints out all results in the Iterator. For each result, print the
 * title, video ID, and thumbnail.
 *
 * @param iteratorSearchResults Iterator of SearchResults to print
 *
 * @param query Search query (String)
 */
private static void prettyPrint(Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults, String query) {

    System.out.println("\n=============================================================");
    System.out.println(
            "   First " + NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED + " videos for search on \"" + query + "\".");
    System.out.println("=============================================================\n");

    if (!iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(" There aren't any results for your query.");
    }

    while (iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {

        SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
        ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();

        // Confirm that the result represents a video. Otherwise, the
        // item will not contain a video ID.
        if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {
            Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();

            System.out.println(" Video Id" + rId.getVideoId());
            System.out.println(" Title: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
            System.out.println(" Thumbnail: " + thumbnail.getUrl());
            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

In file youtube.properties i have saved the developer key for web browser and using eclipse .

An exception is caught as "There was an IO error: null : connect timed out" in a catch block .

Can anyone please tell me where i am going wrong . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Did you check if you have stable internet connection? Connection timeout errors [like this one from github](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/issues/146) are usually caused by unstable wifi/mobile connectivity?